# How to see all the recent changes of admin panel, who did it and when?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-admin-actions

I want to see all the recent actions that has been done, how can i see it?

[image]

Comment: what you mean with "all the recent"? Like 10 min. ago? Or all all?

Comment: django create **django_admin_log** table where you can see additions, changes, and deletions of objects done through the admin interface. For more details, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#logentry-objects